# Is every LL(1) grammar also an LR(1)?

Tags: compiler-construction, lr-grammar

Is every LL(1) grammar also an LR(1)?

Comment: I think I had this question in college one day many moons ago ;)

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that LL(1) is NOT contained in LR(0) (because of epsilon rules).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, since both LL and LR parse the data from Left to Right; and since LL(1) looks ahead only one token it must necessarily be an LR(1).  This is also true for LR(k), where k > 1, since an LR(k) grammar can be transformed into a LR(1) grammar.

The difference between LR and LL grammars comes in that LR produces the rightmost derivation, where as LL produces the leftmost derivation.  So this means that an LR parser can in fact parse a greater set than an LL grammar as it builds up from the leaves.

Lets say we have productions as follows:

```
A -> "(" A ")" | "(" ")"
```

Then LL(1) will parse the string `(())`:

```
(()) -> A
     -> "(" A ")"
     -> "(" "(" ")" ")"
```

Where as the LR(1) will parse as follows:

```
Input  Stack          Action
(())   0       
())    0 '('
))     0 '(' '(' 
)      0 '(' '(' ')'  Reduce using A -> "(" ")"
)      0 '(' A
-      0 '(' A ')'    Reduce using A -> "(" A ")"
-      0  A           Accept
```

For more info see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parsing

Comment: but the sequence(of productions) used by  LL(1) to parse is not always in the opposite sequence(of productions)used by LR(1) to parse. Even though former being the top down and latter being bottom up parser so your reason for all LL(1) to be LR(1) does not seem enough.

Comment: Something being LR does not mean that the parse tree with be identical to the inverse LL parse tree, and the thus parser will not necessarily use the productions in the opposite order.  What it does mean is that an LR parser can correctly parse the same set of strings given the same grammar.

Comment: Does this fact contradicts? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60763/does-my-grammar-contradict-ll-⊆-lr1/60764#60764